# How to retrieve NetworkManager error

Tags: python, dbus

How do I retrieve error messages using the python-networkmanager library found [here](https://github.com/seveas/python-networkmanager/).

I'm just doing `AddAndActivateConnection` call to the `NetworkManager` to connect to a WiFi access point, like so.

```
devices = NetworkManager.NetworkManager.GetDevices()
wifi = devices[0].SpecificDevice()
[access_point] = [ap for ap in wifi.GetAccessPoints() if ap.Ssid == 'foo']
connection_params = {
    "802-11-wireless": {
        "security": "802-11-wireless-security",
    },
    "802-11-wireless-security": {
        "key-mgmt": "wpa-psk",
        "psk": "Super Secret Password Goes Here"
    },
}
NetworkManager.NetworkManager.AddAndActivateConnection(connection_params, wifi, access_point)
```

However, regardless of password I am entering I'm not getting any exceptions or error messages back. When using the nmcli command line client to do the same thing I get a nice error message like so:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.
```

How do I check whether activating a connection succeeded, and if it did not, the error message?

Comment: Will you please show us a part of the script? How are you calling NetworkManager from your code?

Comment: Writing-reading permission on app (app already got permission). Who are you for accessing to app data (root can play with desktop.manager data, user only can play with gui(if not permission required) )?

Comment: @dsgdfg yeah, I stumbled upon this as well, but solved it with a pkla file. My problem is that I _want_ to get errors when something goes wrong, such as having wrong permissions.

Comment: @ShubhamVasaikar Alright, I've added how I call the function.